# How does difference in loads affect current draw

Tags: current-limiting, basic

This is a side question to [487370/limit-charging-current-to-a-smartphone](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/487370/limit-charging-current-to-a-smartphone/487372?noredirect=1#comment1240061_487372). Hopefully it will clear the confusion in my head.

Say we start at 5.5V with a series resistor of 1 ohm, that will leave 5V for the phone and limit to 500mA. However if the phone tries to draw more the voltage will collapse, right? Why is that not happening with, say, LEDs? If you increase the resistance in series, the current decreases no matter how much current the LED wants?

Comment: LEDs aren't resistors (or phones). Simple as that. Beginners sometimes think is EVERYTHING is a type of resistor when it is not.

Comment: Aren't "load" and "current draw" the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that we control LED brightness by limiting current rather than voltage. The reason for this is that the LED, like all diodes, have a non-linear I-V curve.

[image]

*Figure 1. Current versus forward voltage, V<sub>f</sub> for various colours of diodes. Source: [IV curves](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/).*

You might find the loadline tool useful.

[image]

*Figure 2. Simple LED with current limiting resistor.*

[image]

*Figure 3. Loadline graphical solver for 5 V supply. Choose your colour of LED, choose a resistor and see where it crosses the LED curve for your chosen colour. Read off the resultant current on the vertical axis. Source: [Loadline resistance graphic tool](http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/loadline-resistance-graphic-tool/).*

> If you increase the resistance in series, the current decreases no matter how much current the LED wants?

You can see from the curves that an LED has one specific profile that it follows (for a given temperature). This is unlike, say, a computer or motorised toy whose power requirement may vary depending on what it's doing but may still require constant voltage to work properly.

---

The graphs and linked articles are mine.

Comment: Yes but ultimately you control the current by controlling the voltage applied to the led. A constant current power supply modulates voltage  constantly.

Comment: The two interact. The constant current source (which could be just a resistor when a reasonably high voltage source is used) limits the current but it's the LED that determines the voltage at that current.

Comment: Assuming the current source is unlimited, the quantity of current crossing the LED will be defined by the voltage. A constant current supply is just a device which reduces voltage when current is too high and increases voltage when current is too low. Of course the resulting voltage will depend on the LED. But current itself is not something you can control directly. There is always something upstream which adjusts voltage according to current sensing.

Answer (score 3):

> Say we start at 5.5V with a series resistor of 1 ohm, that will leave 5V for the phone and limit to 500mA.

No. The resistor will drop 0.5V if 500mA flows. If the load draws more current, it will drop more voltage. If it draws less current, it will drop less voltage.

That means if your load doesn't draw a lot of current it will see higher than 5V which could damage it, depending on the load.

Similarly, a load could draw more than 500mA and it would just see less than 5V.

The resistor doesn't hard limit the current as much as it reduces the current for a set of conditions compared to if the resistor wasn't there.

> Why is that not happening with, say, LEDs? If you increase the resistance in series, the current decreases no matter how much current the LED wants?

The LED doesn't "want" current. It just wants a certain voltage across it. The current that ends up flowing is a result of that and interactions with the resistor. Any excess voltage from the supply that isn't across the diode must be across the resistor, and voltage across a resistor decides how much current flows through it, and if diode and resistor are in series then the same current must flow through both.